# How to make Localhost node js Api to Publicly accessible

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Any help on the below

I have developed an Rest Api using nodejs that interacts with Mysql DB for CRUD
I am able to achieve by accessing http://localhost:3000/api/user.
so How should I make this url to be publicly accessible to an another user who needs to access this rest api in his application
Apologies for lack of knowledge

Thanks

Comment: Why, you need to deploy your application to a publicly accessible server, of course. Localhost is just to develop your application, then you need to put it somewhere public

Comment: **then you need to put it somewhere public** this is where for me confusing .Could you brief me on how to do it .

Comment: You can use [HEROKU](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs) to deploy your app on their server.

Comment: You can rent a server (there are countless web hosting services out there) and remotely install Linux and deploy your app on it, or, maybe an easier solution, use a ready-made platform like Heroku or Amazon Web Services

Answer (score 0):

You can try followings to expose your local Node.js app to the world (good only for testing/development purposes):

- [localtunner.me](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/)
- [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)
- [Zeit's now](https://zeit.co/now)

> For details reach this article:
> https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/exposing-your-local-node-js-app-to-the-world